Problem while running `yarn build:production` on node version: 21
This is what shows in console
When i run yarn build:production
Node version: 21
Console:
yarn run v1.22.22 $ yarn run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production $ cd public/assets && find . \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.map" \) -type f -delete Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx update-browserslist-db@latest Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme node:internal/crypto/hash:80 this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen, algorithmId, getHashCache()); ^ Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19) at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10) at module.exports (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53) at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16) at handleParseError (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10) at /var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5 at /var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12 at /var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3 at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)    at /var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3 at context.callback (/var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13) at /var/www/pterodactyl/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:71 { opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error', 'error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported' ], library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' } Node.js v21.7.2 error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

``

You have not described the problem. Leave a screenshot or add more details.
